# Storing array and accessing them

Tags: java, arrays

This is the coding which I have used to retrieve data from the "GeneID" column. Using this coding I can print all names under the "GeneID" column. But I want to store each and every names from the column to access those name separately. Can anyone help me with this?

```
String name1[] = new String[100];
int i = 0;
String query = "select distinct GeneID from gene1";
PreparedStatement pest = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = pest.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    name1[i] = rs.getString("GeneID");
    System.out.println(name1[i]);
}

rs.close();
pest.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using array you have to increment `i` inside the `while (rs.next()) {`

```
  String name1[] = new String[100];

    int i = 0;
    String query = "select distinct GeneID from gene1";
    PreparedStatement pest = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = pest.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {

        name1[i] = rs.getString("GeneID");
        System.out.println(name1[i]);
      i++;
    }

    rs.close();
    pest.close();
}
```

For accessing you can iterate over the array

```
 for(int i;i<name1.length-1;i++){
System.out.println("Id is "+name1[i]);
}
```

Or you can use

```
for (String id: name1) {           
   System.out.println("Id is "+name1[i]);
}
```

You can also use [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to store variable like below

```
 ArrayList ar=new ArrayList();

 String query = "select distinct GeneID from gene1";
 PreparedStatement pest = connection.prepareStatement(query);
 ResultSet rs = pest.executeQuery();
 while (rs.next()) {
       String id = rs.getString("GeneID");
        ar.add(id);
    }

    rs.close();
    pest.close();
}
```

For iterating over ArrayList

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Id is "+ar.get(i));
        }
```

or

```
for (String id : ar) {
            System.out.println("Id is "+ar.get(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use arrayList, so that you can use a method of .add(), this proves much helpful

```
List ls=new ArrayList();

ResultSet rsp=pss.executeQuery("select * from student");

while(rsp.next()){


ls.add(rsp.getString("your_column_name"));

}
```

rsp.close();

Comment: Thank You for the response. But How can i access each name stored in "ls" one by one? I need to give each name for each vertexes.